# build a minimal camera (OV5647 + microSD + ?)

Tags: camera, sd-card, raspicam

I want to use the OV5647 camera module to start to store data (as soon as it is fed, I don't know yet whether in photo or video format) to a microSD choosing a specific rate and resolution (e.g. 1080p30) and whether to stop when the memory is full or continue by deleting the older frames to free up space for the new ones (in this case I guess I have to use an image format, right?).

I'll use a 5V DC power source, which components should I use? I need it to be the simplest, lightest, thinnest.

the next step will be to control these settings using display and keys.

any suggestion is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Raspberry Pi Zero has exactly what you need (including your required resolution and frame rate). `raspistill` or `raspivid` are supplied programs to drive the camera.

That's £14 for the camera at https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/raspberry-pi-zero-camera-module and £10 for a Zero with WiFi.

**Note:** I'm not affiliated to Pimoroni, there are other Zero camera suppliers.

Comment: yes I can already do that, but I'd like to do this without an OS, just start writing data immediately once powered

Comment: Are you crazy. I don't think the bare metal folks have any support for driving the camera directly (because it uses a Broadcom proprietary interface). Running Raspbian Lite (no GUI needed) is the easiest way.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, so **indicatively** how much time do you think is required before the camera start recording with this configuration (Zero + Raspbian Lite)?

Comment: My headless Raspberry starts running things in about ten seconds from power on.